# Enter ID in html form and load related data from MySQL database in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form with an input field for a userID. Based on the entered UID I want to load data on the same page related to that userID when the user clicks `btnLoad`. The data is stored in a MySQL database. I tried several approaches, but I can't manage to make it work. The problem is not fetching the data from the database, but getting the value from the input field into my php script to use in my statement/query.
What I did so far:
I have a form with input field `txtTest` and a button `btnLoad` to trigger an ajax call that launches the php script and pass the value of txtTest. 
I have a div on the same page in which the result of the php script will be echoed.
When I click the button, nothing happens...

**Test.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>  
<script>
//AJAX CALL
function fireAjax(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"testpassvariable.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{userID:$("#txtTest").val(),},
                success: function (response){
                    $('#testDiv').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="testForm" id="testForm" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="text" name="txtTest" id="txtTest"/>
<input type="button" id="btnLoad" name="btnLoad" onclick="fireAjax();"
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" id="SubmitButton" value="TEST"/>
</form>
<div id="testDiv" name="testDiv">
</div>
</body>
```

The submit button is to insert updated data into the DB. I know I have to add the "action". But I leave it out at this point to focus on my current problem.

**testpassvariable.php**

```
<?php
$player = $_POST['userID'];
echo $player;
?>
```

For the purpose of this script (testing if I can pass a value to php and return it in the current page), I left all script related to fetching data from the DB out.

Comment: add `dataType:text,` you should be ok

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says 'A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is **ready**.' Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //AJAX CALL
    function fireAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"testpassvariable.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{userID:$("#txtTest").val(),},
            success: function (response){
                $('#testDiv').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct two things:

1) Need to add `$(document).ready()`.

When you include jQuery in your page, it automatically traverses through all HTML elements (forms, form elements, images, etc...) and binds them.

So that we can fire any event of them further.

If you do not include `$(document).ready()`, this traversing will not be done, thus no events will be fired.

Corrected Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //AJAX CALL
    function fireAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"testpassvariable.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{userID:$("#txtTest").val(),},
            success: function (response){
                $('#testDiv').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

`$(document).ready()` can also be written as:

```
$(function(){
// Your code
});
```

2) The button's HTML is improper:

Change:

```
<input type="button" id="btnLoad" name="btnLoad" onclick="fireAjax();"
```

To:

```
<input type="button" id="btnLoad" name="btnLoad" onclick="fireAjax();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for to input! Seems clear to me and it should work, but for some reason when I click `btnLoad` nothing happens. I've added to the php script `echo "User ID is: " $player;`, just to test if it's $player that contains no value or the php script that doesn't run/echoed in the div. It's the latter...

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic but should see you through.

Change

```
<input type="button" id="btnLoad" name="btnLoad" onclick="fireAjax();"/>
```

Change AJAX to pass JSON Array.

```
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "action.php",
data: data,
....
```

// action.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array(
     'a' => $b[5]
));

   //Connect to DB
    $db = mysql_connect("localhst","user","pass") or die("Database Error");
    mysql_select_db("db_name",$db);

    //Get ID from request
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;

    //Check id is valid
    if($id > 0)
    {
        //Query the DB
        $resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $id);
        if($resource === false)
        {
            die("Database Error");
        }

        if(mysql_num_rows($resource) == 0)
        {
            die("No User Exists");
        }

        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);

        echo "Hello User, your number is" . $user['number'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "testpassvariable.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        userID: $("#txtTest").val(),
    },
    dataType: text, //<-add
    success: function (response) {
        $('#testDiv').html(response);
    }
});
```

add dataType:text, you should be ok.
You need to specify the response from the php page since you are returning a string you should expect a string. Adding `dataType: text` tells ajax that you are expecting text response from php

Answer (score 0):

try this:- [for more info go here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnLoad").click(function(){
$.post({"testpassvariable.php",{{'userID':$("#txtTest").val()},function(response){
 $('#testDiv').html(response);
}
});
});
});
```

and i think that the error is here:-(you wrote it like this)

```
 data:{userID:$("#txtTest").val(),}
```

but it should be like this:-

```
data:{userID:$("#txtTest").val()}
```

happy coding :-)